# tfs - how to create checkin alert to find all checkins made in a day

Tags: tfs

I want to create a custom alert to find what all checkins made in a particular day(Only one mail for day).

This alert is not available in the list of existing templates.

With the existing alerts I am getting lot of mails and missing some other mails.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be achieved by TFS alert. Every check-in will trigger an alert. Through TFS alert, you can only set to receive an e-mail notification on other user’s check-ins under a specified folder (such as &/Main) If you want to get all check-in messages, you will have to receive a lot of mails.

To achieve what you need, you should use [TFS API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset(v=vs.120).aspx). Since every check in will generate a changeset in TFS. So you just need to list the need changeset info during a day time. There is a `CreationDate`  properties(*Gets or sets the creation date of this changeset*.)

A example to list all changeset info under a project:

```
var tfsUrl = "http://myTfsServer:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
var sourceControlRootPath = "$/MyTeamProject";
var tfsConnection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsUrl));
var vcs = tfsConnection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var changeSets = vcs.QueryHistory(sourceControlRootPath, RecursionType.Full);

foreach (var c in changeSets)
{
    var changeSet = vcs.GetChangeset(c.ChangesetId);
    foreach (var change in changeSet.Changes) 
    {
       // All sorts of  data in here
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. Actually I tried this. I tried with versioncontrolclient.query history(). Again in that I am not able to get the change sets by passing a particular date. I needed to get all change sets and needs to check for particular date. Is there any option to achieve this in versioncontrolserver?

Answer (score 4):

As Patrick said this *can not be achieved* throgh TFS alerts.
So you can use TFS api checkin event .

Take a look at [ISubscriber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.isubscriber(v=vs.120).aspx) interface.

Create a class library project . Write an event handler class something like

```
public class CheckinEventHandler : ISubscriber
{
         public string Name
        {
            get { return "CheckinEventHandler"; }
        }

         public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get { return SubscriberPriority.Normal; }
        }

         public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode,
                                                    out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {

            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;

             if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is CheckinEvent )
                {
                    //Write info in file

                }
        }

         public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[1] { typeof(CheckinEvent)};
        }
}
```

Compile the project and place the dll in **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins**

In ProcessEvent method write info about the checkin in any type of file .
You can write that in some text file. Append all the information in the same file for a day.

Then create a email dispatcher program something like this :

```
        public bool SendMail()
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add("some emailId");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("some emailId");
                mail.Subject = "Checkin Info";
                mail.Body =//Assign content of the text file here 
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = //e.g. "smtp.gmail.com"
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                     ("userId", "password");

                smtp.EnableSsl = false;

                smtp.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If the method returns true then delete the file programmatically .

And you can schedule this program to run at a fixed time every day using TaskSchedular .

This is how you will get only one email per day and you won't miss out on any checkin either.